# Find a div with a certain class in ancestor

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to find if there is a `div` ancestor with a certain class.

For example I want to be sure the last `input` has an ancestor `div` with a class `surface-modal` - even if there are more div parents.

Thank you for your help

```html
<div class="surface-modal">
  <div class="surface-modal-header">
    <a title="Recharger" class="button_reset_filter action_img" href="#" onclick="surface.link_to(surface.getLastModalUrl(),'tg_modal');return false;"></a>
    <a title="Fermer" class="sf_admin_action_close action_img" href="#" onclick="surface.link_to('default/blank?skipNav=true','tg_modal');return false;"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="surface-modal-content" id="tg_modal" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="title_wrapper">
      <h2>Nouveau fabricant</h2>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <form multipart="1" class="general_form create_form">
      <fieldset id="sf_fieldset_tg_modal_none" class=" create">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="sf_fieldset_tg_modal_supplier" class=" create">
        <h3>Fabricant</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="supplier_name">Nom:</label>
          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="supplier[name]" id="supplier_name" value="" filter_front_wildcard="1" class="input_text surface-form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="supplier_email">E-mail:</label>
          <div class="input_wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="supplier[email]" id="supplier_email" value="" class="input_text surface-form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `.surface-modal input`? More context is needed about what element you're starting from, how you're selecting elements, the events involved etc...

Comment: When or where do you want to do this? If you mean in the event handler associated with an event on the `input`, then it would be `const div = theInputElement.closest(".surface-modal");` ([details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)) which will give you the closest matching ancestor `div` or `null` if none found, but...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("input:last-of-type").parents("div.surface-modal")) {
    // ancestor exists, do something
}
```

"the .parents() method allows us to search through the ancestors of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements ordered from immediate parent on up; the elements are returned in order from the closest parent to the outer ones." - [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: Why do you assume jQuery?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I can't use jquery, do you think it exist a methode without Jquery
Thank you